# Customize endpoints with Spring Data REST

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I've a project with Spring Boot 1.5.7, Spring Data REST, Hibernate, Spring JPA, Swagger2.

I've two beans like these:

```
    @Entity
public class TicketBundle extends AbstractEntity {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 404514926837058071L;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Note> notes = new ArrayList<>();

    .....
    }
```

and

```
    @Entity
public class Note extends AbstractEntity {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5062313842902549565L;

    @Lob
    private String text;
    ...
    }
```

I'm exposing my methods via Repository:

```
@Transactional
@RepositoryRestResource(excerptProjection = TicketBundleProjection.class)
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
public interface TicketBundleRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<TicketBundle, Long> {
....
}
```

so in swagger I see the endpoint in which I'm interested that is needed to load the collection of notes from a specific ticket bundle:

[image]

Now, I want to override the default `GET /api/v1/ticketBundles/{id}/notes` and replace that with my custom method I put in `TicketBundleRepository`:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@RestResource(rel = "ticketBundleNotes", path = "/ticketBundles/{id}/notes")
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "/ticketBundles/{id}/notes")
@Query("SELECT n FROM TicketBundle tb JOIN tb.notes n WHERE tb.id=:id ORDER BY n.createdDate DESC,n.id DESC")
public Page<Note> getNotes(@Param("id") long id, Pageable pageable);
```

It's very convenient create the query in this way because I need to use Pageable and return a Page. Unfortunately I've two problems at this point.

**First problem**
The method is mapped on the endpoint `/api/v1/ticketBundles/search/ticketBundles/{id}/notes` instad of `/api/v1/ticketBundles/ticketBundles/{id}/notes`
[image]

**Second problem**
When I call the method from swagger I receive an HTTP 404:

The request seems wrong. Seems the path variable is not understood:

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/ticketBundles/search/ticketBundles/{id}/notes?id=1'
```

This is the response from the server:

```
{
   "timestamp": "2017-10-05T14:00:35.563+0000",
   "status": 404,
   "error": "Not Found",
   "message": "No message available",
   "path": "/api/v1/ticketBundles/search/ticketBundles/%7Bid%7D/notes"
 }
```

without any error on the server side.

Is there a way to override the endpoint `GET/api/v1/ticketBundles/{id}/notes` exposing it through `Repository` without using a custom controller (using that I would loose the facilities to manage the Pageable)?

Furthermore, what am I doing wrong to get a HTTP 404 in the call I shown above?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are using incorrect annotations. You would need to annotate your class with `@RestController` and use `@PathVariable` on your method instead of `@Param`. Here is a working sample, you may want to tailor it according to your needs.

```
@org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryRestController
@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
public interface PersonRepository extends org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository<Person, Long> {

    @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping(path = "/people/{id}")
    Person findById(@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable("id") Long id);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, according to this https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-1154 it's not possible use @PathVariable into a RestRepository. I tried your example and doesn't work for me. I'm using Spring Data REST. Thanks!