# how to validate path variable in spring data rest?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest

My question is very simple. I am using Spring Data REST, which means I get all the endpoints by default and I am trying to validate the path. So let's say I have

```
/user/{string} [GET operation]
```

Let's say this can only be letters and I want to validate this to ensure it is not null or a number how can I achieve this?

I know one way to do this would be to override the controller, which would give me access to the parameter as it comes in and I can validate it. But this seems like too much for such a simple thing.

Comment: The correct response in that case is to return a 404, which is what the default controllers will do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Customize endpoints with Spring Data REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46587861/customize-endpoints-with-spring-data-rest)

Comment: @OrangeDog no, sorry I looked into it and it doesn't help.

Comment: Why you need to validate the ID? As OrangeDog said, if the ID is not number or the ID doesn't exist in database, Spring Data REST responds with 404. ID validation is unnecessary. If your real path variable is not the ID, use that variable as example instead of the ID.

Comment: it is a string value I have updated the question

Answer (score 1):

To validate path variables you can use custom validators. You can define a custom validator `@NotNumber` to make sure that the path variable is not a number. The explicit check for null is not required since a null path variable will return 404.

**Controller- TestController.class**

```java
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/")
    @Validated
    public class TestController {
    
        @PostMapping("/test/{testVariable}")
        public void signUp(@PathVariable @NotNumber String testVariable) {
            System.out.println(testVariable);
        }
    
        @ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
        @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
        ResponseEntity<String> handleConstraintViolationException(ConstraintViolationException e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Validation Error: " + e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
```

Make sure to add `@Validated` on top of the controller class. This annotation, by default, returns 505 status code. To return 404, we can add the exception handler as seen above.

**@NotNumber interface**

```java
    @Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Constraint(validatedBy = NotNumberImpl.class)
    public @interface NotNumber {
        String message() default "The value of path variable must be String";
    
        Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    
        Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
    }
```

**NotNumberImpl.class - Validator Implementation**

```java
    public class NotNumberImpl implements ConstraintValidator<NotNumber, String> {
        @Override
        public void initialize(NotNumber constraintAnnotation) {
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean isValid(String s, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
            String regex = "^[0-9]";
            return s.matches(regex);
        }
    }
```

The regex pattern can be adjusted according to your requirement.